# Nginx Proxy_pass try_files drop to location handler

Tags: nginx, alias, proxypass

I'm running into small hick up with try_files in combination with proxy_pass (or alias for that matter).

Current config:

```
location /staticsrv {
    alias /var/www/static/trunk/;
    #proxy_pass http://static.localtest.nl/;
}
location ~ ^/staticsrv/images/gallery/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @img_proxy;
}
location @img_proxy {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/?c=media&m=index&imag=$uri;
}
```

However for every file it gets dropped to the rewrite rule as it doesn't exist.
Is there a "trick" (read correct config) to fix my misfortune? Or is it just not possible? Both domains will eventually be on the same server so we can work with alias and proxy_pass.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location ~ ^/staticsrv/images/gallery/(.*)$` needs a `root` or an `alias` to construct a local path for `try_files` to try. Also, you do not necessarily need a regular expression here:

```
location /staticsrv/images/gallery/ {
    alias /var/www/static/trunk/images/gallery/;
    try_files $uri @img_proxy;
}
location @img_proxy {
    rewrite ^ /index.php/?c=media&m=index&imag=$uri last;
}
```

`proxy_pass` will not work with `try_files` as one deals with remote content and the other with local content.

I try to avoid using `alias` and `try_files` in the same location block because of [this open bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

A possible work around would be to use another *intermediate* URI that closely matches the document root:

```
location /staticsrv/images/gallery/ {
    rewrite ^/staticsrv(.+)$ /trunk$1 last;
}
location /trunk {
    internal;
    root /var/www/static;
    try_files $uri @img_proxy;
}
location @img_proxy {
    rewrite ^ /index.php/?c=media&m=index&imag=$uri last;
}
```